# How to convert Range to SortedSet in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections

If I want to convert `Range` to `Set` I can write

```
(0 to 9).toSet
```

What if I need to convert `Range` to `SortedSet`? I can write something like:

```
scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet[Int]((0 to 9): _*)
scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet[Int]() ++ (1 to 9)
```

Does it make sense? Is there any "better" (efficient/simple) way to convert `Range` to `SortedSet`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What could possibly be more simple than this? (You don't need the type parameter or the extra parentheses.)

```
SortedSet(0 to 9:_*)
```

It should also be reasonably efficient.